# Point me in the right direction with this website layout

Tags: html, css

So I am setting up my first website where I want the full display on a computer to have no scrolling - I just want the landing page to have all the information and links. However, when I resize the window to smaller screens I want it to be scrollable and I want the footer to be at the bottom of the page. These images might show the idea:

[This is the mobile verison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqVox.jpg)

[and this is the laptop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2tmw.jpg)

I have managed to build a version of it that resizes correctly but the footer wont show in the laptop version. I enjoy solving problems, but I am lost in finding a good solution for my issue. I found one website that does what I am trying to achieve but the coding originates from some kind of webservice so I cant de-code it: petermckinnon.com

So If any one has an idea on what framework I need to achieve this, I really need a push in that direction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: google media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no code, it's hard to pinpoint your exact problem. I assume it is probably a positioning thing. Nonetheless, I've put together the layout. For the desktop site, I've wrapped everything in one container and gave it a height of 100vh. For the footer's positioning, I did `.footer{position:absolute;bottom:0;}`. This brings it down to the very bottom. I used media queries to make it all responsive.

Here is the example (view in full page):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.fullpage {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.pic-wrap {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

.pic-wrap img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #00ffff;
  height: 85vh;
}

.footer {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 15vh;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .fullpage {
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
  }
  .pic-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
  }
  .content {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .footer {
    height: 15vh;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fullpage">


  <div class="pic-wrap">
    <img src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/RoyaltyFree/Apr17Update/ColourSurge1.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br> Content Here<br>    Content Here<br>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>




</div>
```